# How can I modify the WordPress default widget output?

Tags: filters, widgets

I don't want to style the default widget with only CSS. I want to display the default 'Categories' widget content with my own HTML structure.

Is there available any filter or hook to do that?

Comment: Write your own widget that does what you want. Start by copying the code of the categories widget and do modifications.

Comment: Thanks, I usually follow this trick to do my widget modifications. It's the easier method seems to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To expand on Mark's answer, there's not much (generally) available in the way of filters in the default WordPress widgets (except for perhaps `widget_text`).

But adding your own custom widget is easy - put this in your `functions.php`:

```
require_once("my_widget.php");
add_action("widgets_init", "my_custom_widgets_init");

function my_custom_widgets_init(){
  register_widget("My_Custom_Widget_Class");
}
```

Then you simply want to copy the existing categories widget from `wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-categories.php` to `my_widget.php` in your theme, and change the class name to the same name as that used in the call to `register_widget()` above.

Then make whatever changes you like! I suggest changing the title too so you can distinguish it from the default Categories widget.

Answer (score 12):

You can override the default WordPress widgets by extending them. The code for the default Categories widget can be found on the following link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget_categories/widget/

and below is an example code how you can override the output of the widget.

```
Class My_Categories_Widget extends WP_Widget_Categories {
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // your code here for overriding the output of the widget
    }
}

function my_categories_widget_register() {
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Categories' );
    register_widget( 'My_Categories_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_categories_widget_register' );
```

Comment: And the reason I didn't offer that as an option is that you might want the original behavior at some point, and with your solution you just lose the ability to get it.

Comment: Yes, if you want to have the default widget as it is, it's better to register a totally new widget. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget

Answer (score 9):

You do not need to create a complete new widget to do what you need to do. As I read your question, you are just interested in changing how the categories are displayed on the front end. There are two functions that displays the categories on the front end

- [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) which displays the categories in a list
- [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/) which displays categories in a dropdown list

This all depends on what option was selected in the backend

Now, each of these two functions have a widget specific filter (*`widget_categories_args` and `widget_categories_dropdown_args` respectively*) which you can use to alter the arguments that should be passed to these functions. You can use this to alter the behavior of the list/dropdown. However, this may not be sufficient to do what you want.

Alternatively, each function has its own filter to completely alter the way how these functions should display their output.

They respectively are

- [`wp_list_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_list_categories/)
- [`wp_dropdown_cats`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_dropdown_cats/)

We can use the `widget_title` filter to specifically target the widget only and not other instances of these functions.

In short, you can try the following: (*TOTALLY UNTESTED*)

```
add_filter( 'widget_title', function( $title, $instance, $id_base )
{
    // Target the categories base
    if( 'categories' === $id_base ) // Just make sure the base is correct, I'm not sure here
        add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'wpse_229772_categories', 11, 2 );
        //add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', 'wpse_229772_categories', 11, 2 );
    return $title;
}, 10, 3 );

function wpse_229772_categories( $output, $args )
{
    // Only run the filter once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Get all the categories
    $categories = get_categories( $args );

    $output = '';
    // Just an example of custom html
    $output .= '<div class="some class">';
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        // Just an example of custom html
        $output .= '<div class="' . $category->term_id . '">';
        // You can add any other info here, like a link to the category
        $output .= $category->name;
        // etc ect, you get the drift
        $output .= '</div>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
};
```