# Customizing the output of the archive and category widget without altering the original behavior of the widget

Tags: php, functions, categories, widgets, archives

The current unmodified output looks like this →

```
<div id="archives-4" class="widget widget_archive">
    <h2 class="h2b">Archives</h2>       
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/11/">November 2017</a>&nbsp;(3)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/10/">October 2017</a>&nbsp;(9)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/09/">September 2017</a>&nbsp;(6)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/05/">May 2017</a>&nbsp;(7)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/04/">April 2017</a>&nbsp;(1)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/03/">March 2017</a>&nbsp;(5)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/02/">February 2017</a>&nbsp;(8)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/01/">January 2017</a>&nbsp;(1)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But I want that finally, it should look like this →

```
<div id="archives-4" class="widget widget_archive newinjected_class1">
    <h2 class="h2b">Archives</h2>       
    <ul class="newinjected_class2">
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/11/">November 2017</a>&nbsp;(3)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/10/">October 2017</a>&nbsp;(9)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/09/">September 2017</a>&nbsp;(6)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/05/">May 2017</a>&nbsp;(7)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/04/">April 2017</a>&nbsp;(1)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/03/">March 2017</a>&nbsp;(5)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/02/">February 2017</a>&nbsp;(8)</li>
        <li><a href="http://........./2017/01/">January 2017</a>&nbsp;(1)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Did you realize the new two classes:

```
newinjected_class1
newinjected_class2
```

Is this possible we can achieve this through some filter so that only output is modified without altering the normal behavior of the widget?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no filters for doing this. You would need to create your own version of the widgets in order to achieve this.

You can find the default WordPress widgets in the following folder: `/wp-includes/widgets` in your WordPress installation.

Simply copy the code from within the respective widget .php files in to your theme or plugin:

`class-wp-widget-archives.php`

and

`class-wp-widget-categories.php`

Then just edit the widget code to your liking.

Finally, you'll need to register the widgets using the `register_widget()` function as per the WordPress Codex page - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget. Which should look something like this:

```
function myplugin_register_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'CustomArchiveWidget' );
    register_widget( 'CustomCategoriesWidget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myplugin_register_widgets' );
```

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: Cool. Enlighten me... With jQuery/JS?

Comment: I dont know, but its possible.

Comment: Ok... If you say so... I'd suggest you take a look at the default widget code.

Comment: May be [like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229772/how-can-i-modify-the-wordpress-default-widget-output) but couldnot understand the solution.

Comment: That is the same answer as the solution that I provided above... *Facepalm*

Comment: solution given by Pieter Goosen is different.

Comment: That solution didn't filter what you want to filter and my answer is the only way to change what you want to change

Comment: So creating a new custom widget is the only solution?

Comment: In this case, yes.